# Examples of Gremlin queries with Neo4jClient

Tags: gremlin, neo4jclient

I am building an ASP.NET application with Neo4j database so I am using Neo4jClient. I want to execute Gremlin queries, but I haven't been able to find good examples of writing Gremlin queries with Neo4jClient and C#. Everything I find are Groovy examples with Gremlin console, so I would appreciate if someone could write an example of a basic query in C#, just so that I can figure out how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4jClient no longer supports gremlin queries, if you try to do anything with the `.Gremlin` bits you'll see they are all marked as `Obsolete` and are likely to be removed in the near future.

If you *really* need to see examples, there are a couple of questions on here which have valid Gremlin queries (for example: [neo4j - Issue converting gremlin query to cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332011/neo4j-issue-converting-gremlin-query-to-cypher)) or you could clone the old `bitbucket` neo4jclient repo and look through the wiki ([Gremlin Wiki History](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/commits/c72a530649e47dad07802cc1da085f72005195e5)).

Having said that *all* the examples I see use `client.RootNode` as the base point - this is meaningless (as far as I know) for a Neo4j 2+ as `RootNode` doesn't exist - and I have no idea what will happen if you try to use it.

If you can I would look at `Cypher` it's much *much* nicer and works brilliantly via the client.